# How can I add a shortcut to another Google Drive folder?

Tags: google-drive

A friend of mine has a couple of documents in a Google Drive folder (let's say X).

And I have the rest of the files in another folder, let's say Y.

How can I add a link inside Y so that folder X is visible inside? In other words I'm trying to achieve this:

```
-- Folder Y:
    |-- folder Y files
    |-- Folder X (which is owned by another Drive user)
          |-- Folder X files should show up here
```

There seems to be no option to add a link to another drive.

[image: Google drive options]

Comment: Are you asking how to create a folder shortcut? If so, please read the official help article [Find files & folders with Google Drive shortcuts](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/9700156?hl=en). If you need further help, please edit the question to clarify the question.

Comment: @Rubén This is the answer that I was looking for. Please feel free to delete my question if you want. Thanks for finding this.